# How to set SIP language in Windows Phone Mango?

Tags: windows-phone-7, virtual-keyboard, scoreloop

Is it possible to restrict language of virtual keyboard, or SIP, to a English only? I'm developing a multilingual game with Scoreloop and want to allow users to enter their nicknames in latin only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, but if it were you shouldn't.

Leave the keyboard language selection to the user. It would be very confusing for the user to suddenly have a different SIP.

Just validate the string that is entered.

**EDIT**

You are not looking for an input language but for a character restriction so another option is to [design your own SIP with the characters you want to allow](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx)

Comment: but the case is that Scoreloop requires latin symbols only. The only solution seems is to notify a user that he or she must enter nickname in English...

Comment: yes, and you would need to do that anyway because if you would be able to set the input language you would have to inform the user of that. I added to my answer the option to create a custom SIP.

Comment: I've tried to implement this in XNA for 10 mins, but couldn't get this custom SIP work, I just not very good in Silverlight - is it possible to use this custom SIP in pure XNA?

Comment: I don't think so. You'll need a combination of these at the least. On the other hand: how hard is it to put 26 buttons on a screen to provide input?

Comment: in fast it is quitehard to create a good custom SIP. The standard SIPs scroll the rest of the page out of the way, offer learning suggestions and more ...